# Make second container stick on top right after the first one when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As you can see here : http://www.shadownet.com.mv/products-2/

The first container sticks on top when scrolled vertically from the container. It should end and the second container "SHADOW SERVER SERIES" should stick on top replacing the first one (bringing the first one to the original position) when it is scrolled vertically from the container.

Right now i use this JS code  to make the first one stick but when i use it for the second one, it sticks both on top and doesn't give the intended results :

```
var menu = document.querySelector('#sticky')
var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition) {
    menu.style.position = 'fixed';
    menu.style.top = '42px';
    menu.style.width = '100%';
} else {
    menu.style.position = 'static';
    menu.style.top = '';
}
});
```

I apologize for my bad english, im not a native speaker.

Comment: It sounds as though what you want to do is have a second ID for the top menu, with its own `var menu` equivalent. Then you would run a separate `if` conditional based on the offset from that variable. Inside that conditional you would also run the `else` in your code above. Hopefully that makes sense. Also, for a non-native English speaker, your grammar is much better than most natives! ;)

Comment: Can you add CSS or does it have to be all in JS?

Comment: @ObsidianAge, I'm not sure which condition to use, i'm not very proficient in JS. Haha thanks!

Comment: @TimVermaelen, I can use CSS. Couldn't find a popular browser compatible version for the intended results, so i resorted to that small JS snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular one,

I used [stickyJS](http://stickyjs.com/) which worked wonderfully and out of the box. I was using a wordpress website. I added the script to header.php and added the JS snippet on desired page, set IDs for the two containers and gave z-index so that they go above each other when in view.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use CSS, I would use the `menuPosition` as state in CSS.

So first the JS function would control state:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('#sticky'),
    menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition){
        document.body.classList.add('scrolled');
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('scrolled');
    }
});
```

I've used `classList` which has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
As Obsidian Age pointed out, move the variable `menuPosition` inside the event controller when it's CSS is dynamic from the top.

Then in CSS, use the body state to control offset for both containers:

```
#sticky { display: none; position: static; top: 48px; /*...*/ }
#sticky + #sticky2 { display: none;  position: static; width: 100%;/*...*/ }

.scrolled #sticky { display: block; position: fixed; }
.scrolled #sticky + #sticky2 { display: block; position: fixed; }
```

The `+` in CSS only works if both containers are direct children of the same parent.

Comment: Ofcourse it works, you just need to figure out your CSS, cause I can't really see that part. Create a jsfiddle ...